# Juju - How to add SSH keys to a model after a depoy

Tags: juju

After I deploy some charms with Juju how do I update all the SSH keys in the model if they change?

Answer (score 0):

```
juju add-ssh-key [options] <ssh key> ...
```

Source: [docs](https://jaas.ai/docs/commands#add-ssh-key).

Comment: That worked! https://imgur.com/a/QzZVVOA

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu@zazen:~$ cat  /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa 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 ubuntu@zazen

ubuntu@zazen:~$ juju add-ssh-key "ssh-rsa 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 ubuntu@zazen"